# Select range based on from/to date critera

Tags: excel, vba

I have two spreadsheets (spreadsheet 1) lists payments made based on monthly sales. Some payments are made towards one month, some are towards two months and some are towards month A through Month C. (Spreadsheet 2) lists the sales they have accrued monthly. Below is an example of the spreadsheets.

Spreadsheet 1

```
Payments - Recipient - From - To - Amount
1        - Mark      - May  - Jul - 200
2        - Stacy     - Jan        - 100
3        - Adam      - Feb  - Mar - 50
```

Spreadsheet 2

```
Sales - Jan - Feb - Mar - Apr - May - Jun - July
Mark  -  5  -  10 - 7   - 6   -  8  -  10 -  12
Stacy -  2
Adam  -  1      3 - 6
```

The outcome I am trying to accomplish is to select a range of cells and use them for calculations based on the months the payments were made. For instance, for Mark I want to be able to retrieve the data from May through July which will give me a total of 30. for Stacy only Jan and for Adam Feb and March totaling 9.

If standard formulas isn't possible I would consider VBA as well.

I tried using Index and match but I haven't had any luck.

Comment: Could you format your spreadsheet examples better, so as to show what is below what? Are all those above columns?

Comment: Row 1 Payments - Recipient - From - To - Amount

Comment: Row 2 1 - Mark - May - Jul - 200

Comment: Row 3 2 - Stacy - Jan - 100

Comment: Row 4 3 - Adam - Feb - Mar - 50

Comment: (-) indicates a separate column

Comment: Spreadsheet 2  Row 1 Sales - Jan - Feb - Mar - Apr - May - Jun - July

Comment: Row 2 Mark - 5 - 10 - 7 - 6 - 8 - 10 - 12

Comment: Row 4 Adam - 1 3 - 6

Answer (score 2):

With Mark in K1 May in L1 and Jul in M1 the following formula works
    =SUM(OFFSET($A$1,MATCH($K1,A:A,0)-1,MATCH($L1,1:1,0)-1,1,IF($M1<>"",MONTH($M1&"/1")-MONTH($L1&"/1")+1,1)))

i.e.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that it is formatted for American dates. If non-US, use "1/'&$M1 instead

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for the reply. It doesnt seem to work. In which worksheet did you place the code? I tried on both.

Comment: Let me know if the above image helps. The word 'Sales', need to be in cell A1

Comment: Hi Chris, Here is another difficulty I just came across, suppose I have it listed in multiple years for instance 2013, 2014 and 2015?

Comment: between column K & L for payments, and sales its listed across, thus B1 will be Jan 2013 and so forth

Comment: It depends on how your header row (b1 to h1) is formatted - Date vs text. It would really be best to convert all text values to dates. i.e. Dec 2013 would be 12/1/13. You can adjust the formatting later. The formula would be =SUM(OFFSET($A$1,MATCH($K2,$A:$A,0)-1,MATCH($M2,$1:$1,0)-1,1,IF($N2<>"",DATEDIF($M2,$N2,"m")+1,1)))

Comment: See updated image with formatting adjusted. For help converting text values to dates, you need to to do your own research and/or start a new thread

Comment: and this would be the formula if the header row (the orange one in the picture) is formatted as text AND the year resides in column L. =SUM(OFFSET($A$1,MATCH($K2,$A:$A,0)-1,MATCH($M2&" "&L2,$1:$1,0)-1,1,IF($N2<>"",DATEDIF(DATE($L2,MONTH(DATEVALUE($M2&" 1")),1),DATE($L2,MONTH(DATEVALUE($N2&" 1")),1),"m")+1,1)))  Note that it will not work for dates than span multiple years